# How to evaluate complex contour integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Evaluate the contour integral $$
> \int_C(z^2+4iz)\sin\left(\frac{3}{z+2i}\right)\,dz
> $$ where $C$
>    is the
>   circle $|z| = 3$ oriented in the counterclockwise direction.

Any hint how to start this? Should i use cauchy integral formula or cauchy integral formula for derivatives?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\left(z^2+4iz\right)\sin\left(\frac3{z+2i}\right)
=\left[(z+2i)^2+4\right]\left[\frac3{z+2i}-\frac16\frac{27}{(z+2i)^3}+O\!\left(\frac1{(z+2i)^5}\right)\right]
$$
and consider the residue at $z=-2i$.